# db2: export packages with db2look

Tags: database, db2

is there a way to export the "CREATE PACKAGES" statements with db2look functionality?

I try with the different options but couldn't get the CREATE PACKAGES statements. The reason why I want that is because we copy a PROD db to a TEST DB and the schema for 2 PACKAGES changes name so I just want to recreate them in the right package.

Here is the command I launch:

```
db2look -d DBNAME -a -e -z SCHEMA_NAME -l -o OLDSCHEMA.sql
```

Comment: sorry: db2look -d DBNAME -a -e -z SCHEMA_NAME -l -o OLDSCHEMA.sql

Comment: Do you mean PL/SQL packages (in the Oracle compatibility mode) or the traditional DB2 packages?

Comment: In that case you cannot extract them. There is no `CREATE PACKAGES` statement that creates them. They are created when routines (procedures and functions) are compiled. Why do you think you need to extract the DB2 packages?

Comment: the ones listed when you enter "db2 list packages for all"

Comment: @mustaccio, see comment under the answer please I think it answers your question question about why I want to do that.

Comment: What created those packages in the source database? Do they belong to SQL routines or some embedded SQL programs? And what is your DB2 version and platform, by the way? Both source and target, if they are different.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to recreate packages, because they are only needed for static SQL, and you can override existing ones.

The only way to create the same is by rebinding with the same options in both databases.

Comment: The thing is that I restored a database A into a new one B. In the A DB, the schema for those pacakges where named after the db2admin DBADMIN1. So the full name for the Packages are DBADMIN1.P1 and DBADMIN1.P2. 
In the new DB B, the db admin is named DBADMIN2 and in the DDL file I used to restore the DB the packages where not included and thus there are no DBADMIN2.P1 and DBADMIN2.P2.
Problem is that I use an old soft which looks for those two packages under the name of "the db admin"".P1" or ".P2".
So I just ask how can I copy a certain package to a new schema?

Comment: can you get the bind file, in order to rebind the files with the new user?

Comment: The "why do you want to" isn't helpful.  It should be sufficient to say "I need to do this".

Comment: Packages are an internal representation of the access plan to the data. They are not objects that users can play with. The only thing you can do is to bind it and allow execution on it. That is the reason you should re-rebind them in the new database from the bind file.

Comment: First, you should understand what are the packages before trying to play with (thanks for the "answer is not useful")