# db2 change package schema

Tags: db2, package, database-schema

1. I cloned a DB DB_AAA using *backup* utility.
2. I create a new DB DB_ZZZ
3. Using *db2look*, I create a ddl file containing all tables and schemas from DB_AAA
4. *db2 -tvsf testfile.ddl*
5. db2 -v RESTORE DATABASE DB_AAA
           FROM "/backups"
           TAKEN AT 20130612013105
           TO "/db"
           INTO DB_ZZZ
           REPLACE EXISTING
6. On DB_AAA, the DB2 ADMIN is DB2PADM
7. On DB_ZZZ, the DB2 ADMIN is DB2TADM

After finishing the restore, I have some PACKAGES which are still under the schema DB2**P**ADM which is a big problem because it cannot be acccessed by applications using *DBADMINNAME*.PACKANGE_NAME to retrieve it.

Question: can I modifiy the name of the schema under which a package is installed? I don't have the scripts to recreate manually the packages so it would be my only solution.

Package    Schema    Version     by        sections      Valid   Format   level     Blocking

---

CS16       DB2PADM               DB2PADM              52 Y       0        CS        U
VS16       DB2PADM               DB2PADM              52 Y       0        CS        U

Comment: So you think that [asking the same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351021/db2-export-packages-with-db2look) will somehow produce different answers? And you have not responded to the comments in the original question.

Comment: I think I have answered to all the questions. If you want to know, I thought that maybe I could ask it presenting the subject on another angle. My problem is still alive and no one could answer until now. Do you have something precise to ask me on this topic cause I am more than willing to answer you? Do you consider the problem solved in the previous question...?

Comment: What created those packages in the source database? Do they belong to SQL routines or some embedded SQL programs? And what is your DB2 version and platform, by the way? Both source and target, if they are different.

Comment: target db: db2 v8.2. Let me verify the exact version tomorrow for the source db. 
In the source DB, those packages where created when installing a software. This soft, a quite old PLM soft sits on the DB and the install procedure is mainly db config and tablspace creations, packages and all. But I can't find the scripts which hold those packages creation that's why I'm looking for a way to "simply" move them under another schema, which appears to be impossible. The packages hold basic functions such as fetch, cursor and others. They are sql routines.

Comment: To clarify again (I hope), this software has some built in functions that call routines from the package by the name <DBADMIN_NAME>.<ROUTINE_NAME> but in my case the destination DB's admin name is different from the source's. When I did the restore, it kept the packages under the source's admin name as the schema.

Comment: "_functions that call routines from the package_" -- sorry, this does not make any sense. Functions and stored procedures are both *routines*; they cannot be "from the package": when a routine is compiled, a package is produced and stored in the system catalog. You can re-create a routine's package by recompiling the routine. If the packages belong to routines, you can extract their sources from SYSCAT.ROUTINES.TEXT and re-create the routines in the required schema, which will re-create the packages.